# Upload JSON file to InfluxDB

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, influxdb, bitbucket-api

I am trying to collect Bitbucket API data as a json file and push the data to InfluxDB. I am doing this via Jenkins scripted pipeline.
I am not sure how to convert my json data to points as the data will be dynamic. The script executes without any error but I am unable to see my data in InfluxDB
How can I specify which measurement to use.

Code is as below

```
import groovy.json.*
def result

influxSRV='x.x.x.x:8086'
influxDb='dbname'
measurement = 'ms'

node('master'){
    stage('collect'){
            sh "curl -XGET -u 'xx:yy' https://x.y.z > output.json"
             result = readJSON file: 'output.json'
        sh "curl -iX POST \'http://${influxSRV}/write?db=${influxDb}&precision=ms\' --data-binary \'${measurement},${result}\'"
    }
}
```

But the data is not uploaded. Can anyone let me know what I am missing?

Comment: I dont see no groovy here?

Comment: I edited my question now. I use Jenkins pipeline to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = readJSON file: 'output.json'

sh "curl -iX POST http://${influxSRV}/write?db=${influxDb}&precision=ms --data-binary '${measurement},${result}'"
```

You can then see the output of `curl` in the output.

Comment: I could see the output in console but the data is not getting uploaded the measurement name specified for influxdb. Is there any other way to specify measurement name for json data.

Comment: Try running the full curl command manually and see if something is uploaded. If not your curl needs fixing. From what I remember, Influx does not take JSON.